# How to differentiate (when overloading) between prefix and postfix forms of operator++? (C++)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

Because I've overloaded the `operator++` for an iterator class

```
template<typename T>
typename list<T>::iterator& list<T>::iterator::operator++()
{
    //stuff
}
```

But when I try to do

```
list<int>::iterator IT;
IT++;
```

I get a warning about there being no postifx `++`, using prefix form.  How can I specifically overload the prefix/postifx forms?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Write a version of the same operator overload, but give it a parameter of type `int`. You don't have to do anything with that parameter's value.

If you're interested in some history of how this syntax was arrived out, [there's a snippet of it here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/msg/6da0765460749c4f?dmode=source).

Answer (score 20):

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/12515

```
class Date {
    //...
    public:
    Date& operator++(); //prefix
    Date& operator--(); //prefix
    Date operator++(int unused); //postfix
    Date operator--(int unused); //postfix
};
```

Comment: Postfix operators should return by value, not reference. I guess there might be very strange situations where they can return a reference, but what to? Not this, because it has been incremented...

Answer (score 8):

Postfix has an int argument in the signature.

```
Class& operator++();    //Prefix 
Class  operator++(int); //Postfix
```

Answer (score -1):

everything about operator 
overloading 
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html