# Overloading postfix ++ operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is it some kind of enforced rule that the `overload ++` function must take an `int` as argument to distinguish itself from prefix operators?

Also, In case of prefix `overload ++` function, how does the right hand operand is implicit argument?

E.g `++ClassObj //ClassObj is rhs, but usualy lhs is made implicit`

Comment: Wouldn't that be `operator ++` instead of `overload ++`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to differentiate (when overloading) between prefix and postfix forms of operator++? (C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894804/how-to-differentiate-when-overloading-between-prefix-and-postfix-forms-of-opera)

Comment: There is no 'left' and 'right' hand side since the operator is *unary*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the second issue. Both prefix and postfix `++` are *unary* operators, they do not have a *left-hand-side* and *right-hand-side* operand, but a single operand on which they are applied. That is, in `x++` and `++x`, `x` is *the* operand, not the right hand/left hand, but *the* operand.

Then on why the `int` that is required in the signature of the postfix version, it takes an *artificial* integer argument (which is not used) just to differentiate the signatures and allow the compiler to know that you are declaring/defining a *postfix* `++` and not the *prefix* version of it. Consider it as a tag, more than anything else, since the language requires different signatures.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.. It is defined in the standard.

From standard docs *13.5.7 Increment and decrement*,

> The user-defined function called operator++ implements the prefix and postfix ++ operator. If this function is a member
>   function with no parameters, or a non-member function with one parameter of class or enumeration type, it defines the
>   prefix increment operator ++ for objects of that type. **If the function is a member function with one parameter (which
>   shall be of type int) or a non-member function with two parameters (the second of which shall be of type int), it
>   defines the postfix increment operator ++ for objects of that type.** When the postfix increment is called as a result of
>   using the ++ operator, the int argument will have value zero.

Answer (score 3):

C++ needs to make a difference in the signature of the function. Unfortunately, both `x++` and `++x` have only one real argument, namely `x`. So the C++ designers chose a kind of `hack` in defining one to require a dummy unused int parameter. That results in different method signatures, and thus a way for the C++ compiler to distinguish the prefix from the postfix operator.