# Overloading an operator function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to differentiate (when overloading) between prefix and postfix forms of operator++? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894804/how-to-differentiate-when-overloading-between-prefix-and-postfix-forms-of-oper)

Suppose I need to overload an operator function which performs 2 functions.

For example, the first function handles prefix increment and the second function handles postfix. Is there any different syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already been answered: [How to differentiate (when overloading) between prefix and postfix forms of operator++? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894804/how-to-differentiate-when-overloading-between-prefix-and-postfix-forms-of-oper)

The gist of the answer is that prefix takes no parameter, postfix takes an unused int parameter.

```
A &operator++()    { ... } //prefix
A  operator++(int) { ... } //postfix
```

Cheers,
Aaron