# Getting error in inheriting class in C++: template argument deduction/substitution failed

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors

I am a newbie to c++.

I have written a very simple program which is as below

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class index
{
protected:
    int count;
public:
    index()
    {
        count=0;
    }
    index(int c)
    {
        count=c;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<endl<<"count="<<count;
    }
    void operator ++()
    {
        count++;
    }
};

class index1:public index{
public:
    void operator --()
    {
        count--;
    }
};

int main()
{
    index1 i;
    i++;
    cout<<endl<<"i="<<i.display();
    i++;
    cout<<endl<<"i="<<i.display();
    i--;
    cout<<endl<<"i="<<i.display();
}
```

But when I compile this code in G++, I get this:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40:0,
                 from inheritance.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:480:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, char)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:480:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
inheritance.cpp:40:30: note:   cannot convert ‘i.index1::<anonymous>.index::display()’ (type ‘void’) to type ‘char’
```

**EDIT**
I changed `cout<<endl<<"i="<<i.display();` to `cout<<endl<<"i="; i.display();` and it solved the problem.

But now I am getting

`inheritance.cpp:39:3: error: no ‘operator++(int)’ declared for postfix ‘++’ [-fpermissive]`

Comment: You're trying to pass the return value of a *void* function to an iostream... You probably meant `cout << endl << "i="; i.display();`

Comment: @Borgleader:Thanks ,it solved the problem .But it cannot find my overloaded operators.`inheritance.cpp:42:3: error: no ‘operator++(int)’ declared for postfix ‘++’ [-fpermissive]
`

Comment: post fix operator can be overloaded by  operator++ (int) syntax.

Comment: Your second question is discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894804

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not pass a `void` function to an `iostream`.

Either you function should return a value or an `iostream` or `display()` write itself something (like it seems to be). You can solve your problem by doing :

```
int main()
{
    index1 i;
    i++;
    cout<<endl<<"i=";
    i.display();
    i++;
    cout<<endl<<"i=";
    i.display();
    i--;
    cout<<endl<<"i=";
    i.display();
}
```

Also your `operator++` overloading is wrong, it should be :

```
index operator ++(int)    // Look at the return value
{
    count++;
    return *this;       // return
}
```

Same thing for the `operator--`.

Just take a look at [**this**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) for operator overloading.

Answer (score 0):

A g++ error message that begins with `note:` is just providing more information about why a previous error happened.  With g++ 4.8, I get (among other errors):

```
main.cpp:40:21: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘void’)
     cout<<endl<<"i="<<i.display();
                     ^
```

which pretty well explains the problem.  The type of `i.display()` is `void`, so you can't pass it to `operator<<` like that.

Answer (score 0):

Following line mean you are appending void to stdout and that is not supported.

```
cout<<endl<<"i="<<i.display();
```

So compiler complains as below.

```
"cannot convert ‘i.index1::<anonymous>.index::display()’ (type ‘void’) to type ‘char’"
```

You can do the same with following,

```
cout<<endl<<"i=";
i.display();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the std::ostream& stream parameter into display function:

```
std::ostream& display(std::ostream& stream)
{
   stream << endl << "count=" << count;
   return stream;
}
```

Then you can display the write the object into standard output or into file.