# Implementation of prefix operator

Tags: c++, iterator

i have 2d vector for my hashtable

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > htable;
```

and class for iterator.

```
class myiterator{
    public:
        myiterator();
        myiterator(std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >& v, int ii, int jj) : 
            vec(v), i(ii), j(jj) {}
        myiterator& operator++(); // prefix operator
        myiterator& operator--(); // prefix operator
        std::string* operator->();
    private:
        std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >& vec; // the vector we are iterating over
        int i; // the position in the vector (first dimension)
        int j; // the position in the vector (second dimension)
    };
    myiterator begin() {
        int start=0;
        while(htable[start].size()==0){
            start++;
        }
        return (myiterator(htable, start, 0));
    }
    myiterator end(){
        int end=htable.size()-1;
        while(htable[end].size()==0){
            end--;
        }
        return (myiterator(htable, end, htable[end].size()-1));
    }
```

I've implemented begin and end for iterator, but i have no idea how and what to do with prefix operator. Also, i couldn't google what operator "->" is? 
So, please, can you give me a little trick or article about implementation prefix iterators for 2d vectors? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is how you overloasd pre-/postfix operators in C++:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894804/how-to-differentiate-when-overloading-between-prefix-and-postfix-forms-of-oper

Answer (score 3):

`operator->` is a dereferencing operator.  It allows you to write `it->myFunc()` (that is, allowing an iterator to behave like a pointer).  Typically, you'll return the type your iterator is pointing to.

Your prefix operators (`operator++` and `operator--`) should move the iterator to the next, and previous elements, respectively.

As a side note, if you are overloading `operator->`, you should also overload `operator*()`, and you will probably want to also overload the post-fix operators `myiterator operator--(int)`, and `myiterator operator++(int)`.

Comment: +1 Note: the implementation of the latter (postfix) operators does *not* return a reference to the iterator on which they're being fired. In both cases, a new by-val result iterator is constructed with the current state of `*this` **before** modification. Then `*this` is updated (advanced or retreated), and the by-val temp is the return value, as an `iterator`, *not* as an `iterator&`. This is the main reason postfix operators are more expensive than prefix, which just advances/retreats the iterator and returns `*this` as an `iterator&`.

Comment: Good point.  Added the return value to demonstrate that point. :)

Comment: Sorry for my nooby question, but what is *this ?

Comment: @ratkke in the language sense, it is the instance of your object. For the description of the novel I just wrote, it is "the iterator object" on which you're firing the operator.

Comment: @WhozCraig   But why i need to implement postfix operator for my dereferencing operator?

Answer (score 1):

When you increment your iterator, you basically do the same thing as what you did for begin().

```
if ( j == htable[i].size() - 1 )  // j is at the end of the inner vector
  // set j to zero
  // increment i until htable[i] is not the end of the outer vector and is not empty
else
  // increment j
```

As a side, I would recommend using vector's iterators in place of i and j.  For example:

```
class MyIterator
{
  std::vector< std::vector< std::string > >::iterator i;
  std::vector< std::string >::iterator j;

  // ...
}

MyIterator begin()
{
  std::vector< std::vector< std::string > >::iterator o_iter = htable.begin();
  while ( o_iter != htable.end() && o_iter->empty() )
    ++o_iter;

  // assuming htable wasn't empty...
  return MyIterator( htable, o_iter, o_iter->begin() );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "using vector's iterators".

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain please these 2 lines, 'std::vector< std::vector< std::string > >::iterator o_iter = htable.begin();' and 'return MyIterator( htable, o_iter, o_iter->begin() );' I didn't understand your idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: Using ints will work fine, maybe when your project is done you convert to using a vector's iterators.  htable.begin() will return a vector's iterator to the beginning of htable.  It's just another way of doing it, I wouldn't worry too much about it.